# Creating angular project in eclipse fails with message "Directory \drivers\etc does not exist"

Tags: angular, eclipse

I'm new to Angular and i'm trying to create a new angular project with Eclipse IDE v4.10, Angular IDE 3.0.0
I've installed both Angular and TypeScript IDE, installed NodeJs on my Win7 
and managed to succesfully create and run sample project from CLI.
But when i'm trying to do the same New AngularProject with eclipse, i'm getting error "Directory \drivers\etc does not exist"

[image: Error from eclipse terminal]

Is it possible to make it work or CLI is the only option ?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is four months too late, but replying for the benefit of others who may be running into the same problem.

We've seen the same issues appearing in the Terminal+, when users have had Comodo A/V with Shellcode Injection turned on. Please see [this post](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/terminal-issues-when-using-anti-virus-sofware/) for instructions on how Shellcode Injection can be excluded for CodeMix specific folders. Could also happen if you have another A/V with similar features.

Do reach out to us on our [forums](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topics/codemix/getting-help/) for immediate assistance.